# Rocket Chat rooms.upload PHP Curl not working

Tags: php, rocket.chat

I am using rocket chat API and I want to upload file from my website (which uses PHP) to rocketchat.

Here's my code

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'X-Auth-Token: my__xAuthToken';
$headers[] = 'X-User-Id: myuserid';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://mychatsupport.rocket.chat/api/v1/rooms.upload/myRoomId');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "file=@/var/www/html/mychatsupport/storage/public/images/test.png");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
print_r($result);
curl_close($ch);
```

But, it got an error "File required"

Here is the result of the print_r

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 01 Aug 2019 09:24:17 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: _b6791=http://192.168.46.128:3000; Path=/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Instance-Id: M9xarVOA6BPvkPvFy
Content-Length: 41

{"success":false,"error":"File required"}
```

What did I missed?

Comment: Did you got the solution ?

Comment: yes, I just put the file to array like this `array( 'file' => '@'.$fileFullSavePath.';type='.$fileType.';filename='.$fileName );`

Answer (score 0):

Use CURLFILE with realpath

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://connect.shareslate.com/api/v1/rooms.upload/[roomid]',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('file'=> new CURLFILE(realpath('image.png'))),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'X-Auth-Token: [AuthToken]',
    'X-User-Id: [UserId]',
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
print_r(curl_error($curl));
curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```